# Python 15 puzzle solver with A* algorithm can't find a solution for most cases

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been trying to write a solver for 15 puzzle in python but now I reached a dead end where I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. It works for simple cases, where amount of moves required to solve the puzzle is low, this one for example:

`5 1 2 3
 9 7 11 4
 13 6 15 8
 14 10 0 12`

where `0` represents blank tile.

When I use more complex cases (generated [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/javascript/fifteenj.htm)), the program seems to go into an infinite loop, and even for simple cases I feel like it's not finding the optimal solution. I've been trying to figure out what's causing the problem, but after debugging it for multiple hours I didn't find anything, all of the methods seem to work properly.
Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?
Here's the solver class:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Fifteen:

    heur = ''
    tiles = []
    undo_move = ''
    h_score = 0  # calculated using heuristic
    depth = 0
    previous_moves = []
    zero_x = 0
    zero_y = 0

    def __init__(self, heur, fin, parent=None):
        if parent is None:
            self.heur = heur
            fi = open(fin, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            self.tiles = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in fi]
            self.zero_x, self.zero_y = self.find()
            fi.close()
        elif parent is not None:
            self.heur = deepcopy(parent.heur)
            self.tiles = deepcopy(parent.tiles)
            self.undo_move = deepcopy(parent.undo_move)
            self.depth = deepcopy(parent.depth) + 1
            self.previous_moves = deepcopy(parent.previous_moves)
            self.zero_x = deepcopy(parent.zero_x)
            self.zero_y = deepcopy(parent.zero_y)

    def find(self, tile=0):
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                if self.tiles[y][x] == tile:
                    return x, y
        raise NameError

    def move_tile(self, direction):
        x, y = self.zero_x, self.zero_y
        if direction == 'u':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y - 1][x] = self.tiles[y - 1][x], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_y = self.zero_y - 1
            self.previous_moves.append('u')
            self.undo_move = 'd'
        elif direction == 'd':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y + 1][x] = self.tiles[y + 1][x], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_y = self.zero_y + 1
            self.previous_moves.append('d')
            self.undo_move = 'u'
        elif direction == 'l':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y][x - 1] = self.tiles[y][x - 1], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_x = self.zero_x - 1
            self.previous_moves.append('l')
            self.undo_move = 'r'
        elif direction == 'r':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y][x + 1] = self.tiles[y][x + 1], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_x = self.zero_x + 1
            self.previous_moves.append('r')
            self.undo_move = 'l'
        else:
            raise NameError

    def generate_next_states(self):
        next_states = []
        x, y = self.zero_x, self.zero_y
        if y != 0 and self.undo_move != 'u':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('u')
            next_states.append(child)
        if y != len(self.tiles) - 1 and self.undo_move != 'd':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('d')
            next_states.append(child)
        if x != 0 and self.undo_move != 'l':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('l')
            next_states.append(child)
        if x != len(self.tiles[y]) - 1 and self.undo_move != 'r':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('r')
            next_states.append(child)
        return next_states

    def heuristic(self):
        if self.heur == 'hamm':
            return self.hamming()
        return self.manhattan()

    def hamming(self):
        diff = 0
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                if y == len(self.tiles) - 1 and x == len(self.tiles[y]) - 1:
                    if self.tiles[y][x] != 0:
                        diff += 1
                elif self.tiles[y][x] != y * len(self.tiles) + x + 1:
                    diff += 1
        return diff

    def manhattan(self):
        score = 0
        value = 1
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                if value == 16:
                    value = 0
                x_real, y_real = self.find(value)
                dx = abs(x - x_real)
                dy = abs(y - y_real)
                score += dx + dy
                value += 1
        return score

    def astar(self):

        queue = [self]
        closed_set = {}
        while len(queue) > 0:
            current_state = queue.pop(0)
            closed_set[repr(current_state.tiles)] = current_state
            if current_state.heuristic() == 0:
                print(current_state.tiles)
                print(current_state.previous_moves)
                print(len(current_state.previous_moves))
                return
            for state in current_state.generate_next_states():
                if repr(state.tiles) in closed_set:
                    continue
                state.h_score = state.heuristic()
                queue.append(state)
            queue.sort(key=lambda x: x.h_score, reverse=False)
        print(-1)
        return
```

And this is how I run it:

```
from fifteen import Fifteen

f = Fifteen('manh', "start.txt")
f.astar()
```

The first argument can be either `manh` or `hamm`, depending on the heuristic used, second one is name of file containing initial puzzle setup.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? It's hard to read when the class body is not indented, and the indentation might have an effect on the bug. Also, the `line` variable in the `__init__` method isn't defined anywhere, so as written your program will raise an exception when it tries to use it. Did you change that part when you posted the code here?

Comment: I fixed the indentation, it moved when I pasted the code, in my project it's correct. And I don't think the `line` variable needs to be defined as it's only used in the `for` loop used to read from file.

Comment: Ah, I see that the line variable is in a list comprehension - that makes more sense. Not sure why I didn't spot that when I looked last time.

Comment: And thank you for fixing the indentation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to improve your code, but I will explain main problems (at least for me).
1- You are not using depth values of states while sorting states. This will prevent algorithm finding optimal solutions, or even finding a solution if the state space is large.
2- You should really decide how you represent a "state". I added a equality overload (`__eq__` method) for a state which I think is correct for this problem. It compares tiles, heuristic scores and depth values. Although that was not the main problem I think that is something very important. Because naive implementation may slow down your algorithm a lot and make things hard to debug.
3- When things does not work, try visualizing your algorithm. I added a PrintState function and tried to observe what is wrong with the solving process.

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Fifteen:

    heur = ''
    tiles = []
    undo_move = ''
    h_score = 0  # calculated using heuristic
    depth = 0
    previous_moves = []
    zero_x = 0
    zero_y = 0

    def __init__(self, heur, fin, parent=None):
        if parent is None:
            self.heur = heur
            fi = open(fin, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            self.tiles = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in fi]
            self.zero_x, self.zero_y = self.find()
            fi.close()
        elif parent is not None:
            self.heur = deepcopy(parent.heur)
            self.tiles = deepcopy(parent.tiles)
            self.undo_move = deepcopy(parent.undo_move)
            self.depth = deepcopy(parent.depth) + 1
            self.previous_moves = deepcopy(parent.previous_moves)
            self.zero_x = deepcopy(parent.zero_x)
            self.zero_y = deepcopy(parent.zero_y)

    def find(self, tile=0):
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                if self.tiles[y][x] == tile:
                    return x, y
        raise NameError

    def move_tile(self, direction):
        x, y = self.zero_x, self.zero_y
        if direction == 'u':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y - 1][x] = self.tiles[y - 1][x], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_y = self.zero_y - 1
            self.previous_moves.append('u')
            self.undo_move = 'd'
        elif direction == 'd':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y + 1][x] = self.tiles[y + 1][x], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_y = self.zero_y + 1
            self.previous_moves.append('d')
            self.undo_move = 'u'
        elif direction == 'l':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y][x - 1] = self.tiles[y][x - 1], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_x = self.zero_x - 1
            self.previous_moves.append('l')
            self.undo_move = 'r'
        elif direction == 'r':
            self.tiles[y][x], self.tiles[y][x + 1] = self.tiles[y][x + 1], self.tiles[y][x]
            self.zero_x = self.zero_x + 1
            self.previous_moves.append('r')
            self.undo_move = 'l'
        else:
            raise NameError

    def generate_next_states(self):
        next_states = []
        x, y = self.zero_x, self.zero_y
        if y != 0 and self.undo_move != 'u':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('u')
            next_states.append(child)
        if y != len(self.tiles) - 1 and self.undo_move != 'd':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('d')
            next_states.append(child)
        if x != 0 and self.undo_move != 'l':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('l')
            next_states.append(child)
        if x != len(self.tiles[y]) - 1 and self.undo_move != 'r':
            child = Fifteen(None, None, self)
            child.move_tile('r')
            next_states.append(child)
        return next_states

    def heuristic(self):
        if self.heur == 'hamm':
            return self.hamming()
        return self.manhattan()

    def hamming(self):
        diff = 0
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                if y == len(self.tiles) - 1 and x == len(self.tiles[y]) - 1:
                    if self.tiles[y][x] != 0:
                        diff += 1
                elif self.tiles[y][x] != y * len(self.tiles) + x + 1:
                    diff += 1
        return diff

    def manhattan(self):
        score = 0
        value = 1

        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):

                if value == 16:
                    value = 0
                x_real, y_real = self.find(value)
                dx = abs(x - x_real)
                dy = abs(y - y_real)
                #print("dx + dy for {}: {}".format(value, dx+dy))
                score += dx + dy
                value += 1
        #print("Score:{}".format(score))
        return score


    def PrintState(self):
        for y in range(len(self.tiles)):
            for x in range(len(self.tiles[y])):
                cellValue = self.tiles[y][x]
                print(cellValue, end=" ")
            print("")


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.tiles == other.tiles 
                and self.h_score == other.h_score
                and self.depth == other.depth) 

    def astar(self):

        queue = [self]
        closed_set = {}
        while len(queue) > 0:

            print("---")
            print("---")

            current_state = queue.pop(0)
            print("current state")
            #print(current_state.tiles)
            #print(repr(current_state.tiles))
            current_state.PrintState()
            print("current scores")
            print("heuristic:{}".format(current_state.heuristic()))
            print("depth:{}".format(current_state.depth))
            print("total:{}".format(current_state.heuristic() + current_state.depth))

            closed_set[repr(current_state.tiles)] = current_state
            if current_state.heuristic() == 0:
                print(current_state.tiles)
                print(current_state.previous_moves)
                print(len(current_state.previous_moves))
                return
            for state in current_state.generate_next_states():
                if repr(state.tiles) in closed_set:
                    continue

                state.h_score = state.heuristic()
                queue.append(state)
            queue.sort(key=lambda x: (x.h_score + x.depth), reverse=False)


        print(-1)
        return
```

Optionally, consider using priority queue based implementation.
Update: Beware unsolvable starting positions like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 10 8
9 7 11 12
15 13 14 0
```

I wasted a good time on this configuration :)